# Browser extension: is there a way to stop the loading of images?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

In either Firefox/Chrome extension, is there a way to stop the loading of `<img>` **before** the browser actually starts loading them from a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popular [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) extension for Firefox has this feature, under its images menu

Comment: @David Caunt: but how do they do it?  I am not interested in knowing **which** extensions can do it (of course this is helpful if I get to the point of reverse-engineering an extension to get my answer).

Comment: An xpi is just a zip file - you can extract it and view the source

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox it is possible, in Chrome it in not possible yet, but this is a common request from extensions developers, so they are working on it (Chrome devs are mainly worried about performances hit).